# Order search results by frequency of the search item in a list of fields in Solr

Tags: solr, content-search

We have a requirement to order search results based on the number of occurrence of the search  term in a list of fields(not all the fields).
We tried the below query in sort, but this does not provide the correct sort order.

```
sum(termfreq(field1,"searchQuery"), termfreq(field2,"searchQuery")<and other fields>)
```

We have tried using the "score" from solr but its not providing correct result based on the number of occurrence of the search term in the required fields.

Is there anything available out of the box form solr for this requirement or any other function available from solr other than termfreq ?

Sitecore 9.3
Solr 8.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [query-time boosting](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/search-result-boosting.html#query-time-boosting) to achieve a similar result. Query-time boosting lets you add more weight to specific parts of the query. For example, you can add bosting to a `Title` field so that results with keyword matches in the `Title` field have a higher relevance score than matches in the `Description` field:

```
query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(term).Boost(boostFactor) || 
                 x.Description.Contains(term));
```

Results are sorted by `score` by default so you will not need to apply additional sorting after this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anna, we have tried boost, but the problem being, boost does not consider the number of occurrence. e.g. if 2 fields contains the term then the score is calculated as same irrespective of number of occurrence of the term in the fields

Comment: I see, term frequency is one of the main factors in the Solr scoring algorithm, but there are also additional factors such as frequency of rare terms and field length so the order may not be as precise as when using `termfreq()`. If the standard scoring does not work for you, then you can try constructing a SolrNet query as shown in the example here https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/using-solr-to-group-search-results.html and passing `termfreq()` function in the sort order field.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anna, but LINQ is used in the existing implementation and it would be very tricky right now to change the search implementation and use ISolrQuery now. We are using IQueryable GetResults and building own query and facets using LINQ. Let me know, if there is any solution you could think of to implement sort in LINQ implementation.